# jupyter notebook problem with python 2.7.3

Tags: python, python-2.7, jupyter-notebook

Start getting this error out of nowhere when trying to run jupyter notebook. I have latest python installed as well but this mac-python problem is the issue here I guess that tries to run from python2. Any links to guides/tutorial to maintain both pythons would be helpful as well, but looking for to this fix right now.

````
  File "/anaconda2/bin/jupyter-notebook", line 7, in <module>
    from notebook.notebookapp import main
  File "/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/notebook/notebookapp.py", line 60, in <module>
    from tornado import httpserver
  File "/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tornado/httpserver.py", line 33, in <module>
    from tornado.http1connection import HTTP1ServerConnection, HTTP1ConnectionParameters
  File "/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tornado/http1connection.py", line 30, in <module>
    from tornado import iostream
  File "/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tornado/iostream.py", line 40, in <module>
    from tornado.netutil import ssl_wrap_socket, _client_ssl_defaults, _server_ssl_defaults
  File "/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tornado/netutil.py", line 44, in <module>
    _client_ssl_defaults = ssl.create_default_context(
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'create_default_context'```


$ python3 -V
Python 3.7.4

$ python -V
Python 2.7.3 :: Continuum Analytics, Inc.
````

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. `conda update pip` worked for me.